# Using multiple log4j configuration files

Tags: java, logging, log4j, configuration-files

I have an application which is deployed as jar and is executed by some other parent application. The parent application has defined a [log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j) configuration file and the file is mentioned while starting the parent application.

When I am trying to use log4j instance for child application, its configuration file is never picked. How can I use a different configuration file for my application without impacting configuration file of the parent application?

Comment: Which version of log4j are you using? How exactly is the parent application running your application - is it simply calling your code from within the same JVM instance, or is your jar actually running as a separate process?

Comment: Using 1.2.16 version of log4j. Parent application is calling my code from same JVM instance. When Parent application is starting, a log configuration file is mentioned as start up parameter and thus child configuration files are not picked.